# Getting error Network is unreachable for File_get_contents

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have been using file get contents to get the content of following site however i am getting the following error 
 can anyone explain why so?

> file_get_contents("https://www.watchserieshd.co"): failed to open stream: Network is unreachable

Also i have tried it via curl go the error

> Failed to connect to watchserieshd.co port 80: Connection refused

Comment: It works perfectly fine when I try. Have you tried fetching some other URL? What OS are you running this on? Checked your firewall to make sure PHP can make outgoing HTTP calls?

Comment: Is the url reachable from your browser?

Comment: I am running it diretly via my hosting server.its basically shared windows hosting any suggestions?

Comment: Well, as I suggested in my first comment, have you tried with some other URL's to see if it's only that URL or all? That would be a pretty good first step. If you have this issue with multiple URL's, then contact the hosting provider.

Comment: No its working for many of urls but just two @MagnusEriksson